# Where does sending emails go? Service layer or web layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, design-patterns

I've been having this design-pattern problem for weeks. Where do I put the logic for sending emails? Behaviors can be accessed through the asp.net mvc web interface or through a wcf endpoint hosted inside the asp.net app.

Here are the features of the app:

1. Email notifications.
2. Template rendering - This means I have to know the url structure (actions, base address, etc).

Currently, I am storing base url and paths inside the web.config file and having this email service inside the service layer.

One particular feature is sending confirmation emails to the user and sending the generated confirm url to them. (no idea how to generate this url from the service layer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Emails should never ever ever ever be served from the web layer.  You never want a user to wait while an email is sending.

The best thing to do is create a persistent email queue ( sql is fine ) which another job accesses to send the email.  This gives you the ability to re-send failed emails and run them completely outside your web request thread.

Comment: Never ever ever ever? Pretty broad statement.

Comment: Where would I generate the email message? I need to create an absolute URL to send to the user. But it can be triggered by either wcf or asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 4):

What jfar say is true; that said, you *could* use [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) to generate your emails and then store those emails in a database, again, as jfar suggests.

From the postal website:

> Postal lets you create emails using
>   regular MVC views.

That means you'll have an `Email` folder under your `Views` folder; those views are actually your email templates and have full access to all Html and URL helpers any other view has which will probably make it easy for you to generate a confirm URL or whatever it is that you may need.

Postal includes and `IEmailService` interface with a concrete `EmailService` implementation. This service allows you to directly send an email message or, even better, *generate a regular* `MailMessage` *object*. You could then just store the ready-to-go email in a table on your db and send it later on with a background job.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run an SMTP server on your web server machine, and simply have your business logic layer send mails to that SMTP server.

As long as the SMTP server is up and running, there will be no performance hit on your web application, and the SMTP server itself queues incoming requests and handles them in the background.

Comment: Not all SMTP servers behave this way. But since this is ASP.NET, using a local IIS SMTP and delivering to it using a pick-up directory would do the trick quite nicely.