# How to run background code in a asp.net-mvc/wcf app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, email

Based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293349/where-does-sending-emails-go-service-layer-or-web-layer), I need to put emails in a queue and have a background task run and send them. How do I do this with an architecture that is of ASP.NET-MVC and WCF?

1. How do I build a queue (sql server)?
2. How do I build a background task?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a great way to do it, but the fact it's on NuGet makes it attractive. :) http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottHanselman+%28Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skin this cat many different ways.  The key being that the actual sending of the emails is asynchronous to the queuing of the email.

1. Queue messages via WCF Service using MSMQ binding via this series of blog posts, which assumes IIS 7: [MSMQ, WCF, and IIS: Getting Them to Play Nice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx).
2. Queue messages to MSMQ.  MSMQ is a nice (sometimes underutilized) queue service built into Windows.  You'll write a Windows service to receive messages from this queue.  If you have IIS 7, then check out [Death to Windows Services, Long Live AppFabric](http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/09/08/death-to-windows-services-long-live-appfabric.aspx).  MSMQ is a breeze, but has some quirky constraints (4MB message size and availability)
3. Queue messages to a 'sql queue'.  Create a table to hold basic queued message information and then stored procedures to wrap the queue semantics (e.g. you don't want multiple consumers to receive the same message).  Not difficult, but a little time consuming to get right.
4. Queue messages to Service Broker (or even MSMQ) and write a Windows service that receives messages from the Service Broker Queue.  Service Broker handles the queueing semantics (competing consumers) for you.  The downside is that its a pain in the ass to administer.

HTH,

Z

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is independant of the fact you're using MVC.

The way I've implemented this in the past is to persist the fact you need to sent an e-mail into the database and then process this using a Windows Service.

Another way to do this would be to utilize MSMQ as your storage medium. In general, MSMQ shouldn't be used to "store" data, only as a message transport mechanism, but it's certainly an option in this case.

In terms of developing a "queue", if the e-mails need ordered delivery for some reason, simply having a "RequestedDTTM" column in your database table would allow you to send them in the order they were requested.

Lastly, I would consider implementing a simply multi-threaded e-mail sender to maximize performance. Using the TPL in .NET 4.0 would make this pretty easy. Alternatively, you could use something like the SmartThreadPool library (available at codeplex.com) to manager your e-mail sender threads.

As was mentioned in the other answer you linked to, your UI shouldn't be doing this e-mail sending.